# Why does hovering on some SE links in posts and comments not show a tooltip or at least a title?

Tags: bug

I find that when I move my mouse over a link to a post within the SE network, a "reveal" of the link will show in the bottom left corner of Chrome. Sometimes it shows the actual Question / Title, and sometimes it is just numbers. Why is that?

Further, sometimes the mouseover will show the title of the question in a tooltip, but sometimes not. What is up with that?

As an example, look at the links in the 2nd and 3rd comments in [this UX question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/39023/what-is-the-optimum-button-size-of-touch-screen-applications). You can simply mouse over this link - in my browser the full title shows in the lower left corner, but no tooltip, so it splits the difference of the two cases in the actual linked page (and is faster to try out).

Answer (score 1):

Thagt's just down to the way the commenters wrote the comment. [Stack Exchange use Markdown syntax for formatting comments](https://ux.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

So the syntax used in the first comment is:

`You might be interested in [this previous question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/22719/11687). There are many factors that affect minimum button size (including hardware). It's also worth pointing out that the minimum size isn't the same as the "optimum" size.`

And the second comment is:

`probably a duplicate of https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/smallest-button-size-and-spacing-for-a-touchscreen the accepted answer states: "tl;dr? It all boils down to the pixel density".`

The first link the commentor used the markdown format, whereas the in the second the commentor just pasted in the raw link.

Comment: OK. So, why is your first example *link* just numbers and the second has a Title embedded in it? And if I did it the same way as the first example (arguably the proper way), why does mine not have a tooltip, when your second example (done more carelessly) does? Are you saying that If I want a tooltip, I should NOT use the markdown formatting? My example (in the question above) was done as a Question so the formatting was by clicking the "link" (chain) icon thing. Should I not do that so that I get a tooltip? This is at best inconsistent and seems like a bug to me.